# Is there any difference between regular and "split" hardpoints?

Tags: gratuitous-space-battles

They say that preparation is half the battle, and that definitely applies to Gratuitous Space Battles, where I might go even further by saying that preparation is more than half the game. Seeing how I spend quite a bit of time designing new ship layouts, I've come across the following question:

All ship hulls have a set number of hardpoints where weapons can be mounted. Some hardpoints are "split", and have a pair of white lines connecting them to points on the ship's hull, as can be seen on the lower hardpoint equipped with a weapon in the following screenshot:

[image: Split and non-split]

Now, these two hardpoint types differ from each at least visually, as the weapons mounted  on the split hardpoint will show up in both linked locations:

[image: Let's get visual]

What I would like to know is if there is an actual difference between the two hardpoint types that is not purely cosmetic. Is there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is absolutely no difference in terms of damage etc. The only difference is cosmetic in that two (smaller) projectiles show in battle.

But good question as I remember having the same question when I played.

If I remember correctly, I read this somewhere on the GSB website or forum, but that was quite a while ago, so it would be difficult for me to come up with a link.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the recommendation on *Space Pirates And Zombies*, I'll definitely check it out!

Comment: @Aubergine, thanks for the edit. It was a bit too much like a forum post :D

Comment: Don't mention it. And I must thank you again for recommending SPAZ, it's pretty awesome.